# sound as3 play(startTime) with big mp3

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

I've got a big audiofile (3.5+ hours).
I play this sound in my **AS3 project** with method `.play(startTime)` of `flash.media.Sound class`.
And if `startTime` is more than `12173943` (3h 22m 53s) this audiofile stops. 
If `startTime` is equal or less than this number, I can listen this sound to it's end normally.

This error happens only if I use standart *Air browser* or *Chrome*, in *Safari* and *Firefox* my program works fine. 
Unfortunately, Air browser and Chrome are the most important browsers in my project.

Are there any alternatives for playing sound with big `startTime` or alternatives for using standart sound AS3 class? 
Are there other solutions to this problem?

Comment: the corresponding ```startTime``` value of 12173943 miliseconds must somehow correspond to maximal 32bit unsigned integer. 12173943/1000*44100*2*4 is just about 2^32. As alternative I can point you to Flixel class that allows perfect sound looping. It uses sample data events to extract data. Maybe it will be a workaround for this. http://www.1bardesign.com/src/flixel/FlxSound.as

Comment: 12173943 is between 2^23 and 2^24. I've checked, that my sound object get correctly this number as attribute 'position'. Thanks for link, I'll try it.

Comment: You must have a lot of free RAM.. The alternative to `Sound` class (saves into ram) is `Netstream` which is perfect for streaming long files (I think the timestamps can hold up to 24 hours or more). Anyway to do a test: (using some media converter) Put your MP3 inside an FLV container (no video track, FLV supports extended timestamps) and play via Netstream. If this works fine for you can still do it without converting all your MP3 files but thats for later..

Comment: I'll try this class, but I don't think, that problem is in RAM. I've tried several files with different weight, but all of them can't play from the same time, but they can if I run them from time smaller than this value.